# Check if function is differentiable

Tags: functional-analysis

I've got a function
$f(x) \;=\; \begin{cases} |x|^{\alpha}\sin (1/x) & \text{if }x \ne 0 \\ 0 & \text{if }x=0\end{cases}$

And i tried to solve it. 
At first i calculated left-side limit for $\alpha = 1$ $a=0$
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0^{-}}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} = \frac{|h|sin\dfrac1h}{h}$$
And from here i saw that $|h|$ gonna be a negative number so it will result in 
$$-sin\dfrac1h$$
and for right-side limit and $\alpha = 1$ i will get 
$$sin\dfrac1h$$ so, it will give us that function is not differentiable in 0. 
Changing alpha to $\alpha=2k$, it is, even alpha, this function will be differentiable... Is it correct approach? Can we do it better? I will be greatful for any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Write the limit for the general case, see if you can figure out when is it zero (when exactly is the misbehaving sine neutralized).

Comment: I can't figure out from general case, that's why i tried to do this "around". :)

Comment: You should remove the "$\lim$" symbol in your first displayed formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the derivative at $0$:
$$
\left|f'(0)\right|=
\lim_{h\to 0}\left|\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}\right|=
\lim_{h\to0}\left|\frac{\left|h\right|^a \sin \left(\frac{1}{h}\right)}{h}\right|=
\lim_{h\to 0}\left|h\right|^{a-1}\left|sin\frac{1}{h}\right|
$$
Clearly, if $a>1$, the limit is $0$, as the sine is bounded by $1$, and $\left|h\right|^{a-1}$ tends to $0$. If $a=1$, as you have noticed, the limit does not exist, since $\sin\frac{1}{h}$ has no limit at $0$. That's because it assumes every value from $[-1, 1]$ in every neighbour of $0$. And if $a<1$, situation is even worse - the $\left|h\right|^{a-1}$ part is unbounded, and $\left|h\right|^{a-1}\sin\frac{1}{h}$ assumes every value from whole $\mathbb{R}$ in every neighbour of $0$.

To sum up: $f$ is differentiable iff $a>1$.

Comment: ah like this... thanks :-)